# Default list views like all records or recently viewed having different columns depending on user's profile/group etc.?

Tags: lightning, profile, list, visibility, view

Is it possible to configure default list views like recently views to have pre configured columns based on user type (profile, group) or the only option is to restrict view visibility by creating custom list view? Also, I am talking here about Lightning experience

Comment: This is not possible, but, you can add different list views to different users and profiles, and set different columns on these list views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box way to do this. If you have to have it you could use formula fields and field level security.

Say you have an object and fields

```
Employee
(name, salary, manager)
```

and two profiles

```
VP - Should see Name and Manager on list view, but have access to salary
HR Manager - Should see Name and Salary on the list view but still have access to manager
```

You'd have to create formula fields and field level security

```
xSalary (only HR Managers)
xManager (only Vps)
```

Then your list view would be

```
Name, xSalary, xManager
```

I don't recommend this, b/c it'd be a nightmare to manage and confusing for other admins in the future. If you do it, document heavily.